# How can I get Vista Explorer to keep the same view the whole time?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer

Everytime I browse to a new folder in Windows Explorer on Vista it shows me a different view: thumbnail, details, whatever. In previous Windows versions I found a way to prevent this: switch off "remember each folder's settings" or something similar.

Is there anything like that in Vista?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this answer of mine to [What registry entries should be changed upon a fresh installation of windows?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1597/what-registry-entries-should-be-changed-upon-a-fresh-installation-of-windows/2142#2142), as well as my link to [Fixing Folder Type Problems in Windows Vista](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/fixing-folder-type-problems-in-windows-vista/).

Comment: thanks for that. But before I start changing my registry, I have one question: my bags folder has got **loads** of entries, not one of them "AllFolders". Do I need to change them manually?

Comment: No, if you delete Bags entirely it will be re-created empty; resetting remembered folder types for all folders. (Same step as [here](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/fixing-folder-type-problems-in-windows-vista/).)